# Question mark and equals sign not showing up in wordpress post_name

Tags: php, wordpress, character, urlencode

So I want to add the following `?matchPostId=$matchId` in `post_name` on `wordpress` using `wp_insert_post();`

I tried using `urlencode(); and urldecode();` but still can't get it to work, checked everywhere but seems like the question mark and equals sign is always slashed out in the url of my post. Does anyone know why it does that?
Here is my code:

```
$questionm = '?';
        $equalsm = '=';
        $tipsPage = $questionm . 'matchPostId' . $equalsm . $matchId;


        $post_idpost = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
                'ping_status' => 'closed',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_name' => $tipsPage,
                'post_title' => $value['test']
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_content' => "test"                

            )           
        );
```

Also tried this:

```
$questionm = ('?');
$equalsm = ('=');
urlencode($questionm); 
urlencode($equalsm); 


            $post_idpost = wp_insert_post(
                array(
                    'comment_status' => 'closed',
                    'ping_status' => 'closed',
                    'post_author' => 1,
                    'post_name' => urldecode($questionm) . 'matchPostId' . urldecode($equalsm) . $matchId,

Same problem, the question mark and equals sign is removed from the url.
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask... Indeed if you ``urlencode()`` the full query string those characters _will_ get replaced, since they are reserved characters inside URLs. You need to `urlencode()` the _values_ and _keys_, not the full _string_.

Comment: I tried this still same problem: 

$questionm = ('?');
$equalsm = ('=');
urlencode($questionm); 
urlencode($equalsm); 
    
  
      
 'post_name' => urldecode($questionm) . 'matchPostId' . urldecode($equalsm) . $matchId

Comment: I don't think postname can have ? = in it, it has to be a sanitized version https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#parameters

Comment: thanks, no wonder it doesnt work..

Answer (score 0):

WP sanitizes postname in the wp_insert_post function.

```
if ( empty($post_name) ) { 
    if ( !in_array( $post_status, array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) { 
        $post_name = sanitize_title($post_title); 
    } else { 
        $post_name = ''; 
    } 
} else { 
    // On updates, we need to check to see if it's using the old, fixed sanitization context. 
    $check_name = sanitize_title( $post_name, '', 'old-save' ); 
    if ( $update && strtolower( urlencode( $post_name ) ) == $check_name && get_post_field( 'post_name', $post_ID ) == $check_name ) { 
        $post_name = $check_name; 
    } else { // new post, or slug has changed. 
        $post_name = sanitize_title($post_name); 
    } 
}
```

Source: http://hookr.io/functions/wp_insert_post/ circa line 3094